# mysql #1064 error for parenthesis around FROM

Tags: mysql, union

I am facing a weird issue while trying to run following query :

```
SELECT a, b
FROM (
x_tbl AS tbl
)
UNION
SELECT a, b
FROM (
y_tbl AS tbl
)
```

where x_tbl and y_tbl are 2 tables with common columns a and b.

this query works fine if i do like (no parenthesis) :

```
SELECT a, b
FROM 
x_tbl AS tbl
UNION
SELECT a, b
FROM 
y_tbl AS tbl
```

any idea why ? The same query with parenthesis works fine on a different server but doesn't work on my local.

Answer (score 1):

This appear to be connected to an [old MySQL parser bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4805). Are you using a version older than 5.0?

Comment: php info says : mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 304625 $

Comment: Well, some people still report certain problems as far as 5.0.27. What's the version on the server it works on?

Comment: I did some tests and found that it works fine for mysql 5.l.92 and 5.1.58 but doesn't work for mysql 5.5.14

Comment: those using xampp in windows ...  may face the same issue in xampp 1.7.4 or above ... as it has mysql version 5.5.X

Comment: It may just be a build difference. Is there a reason why you have to use parentheses in the FROM clause?